# Import css from public/assets folder in react js gives "Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported"

Tags: reactjs, import, fonts

I generated a font kit and trying to import it in my project. I am getting this error

[image]

I know if I put the font folder inside `src` then it will work but I want to keep fonts inside the assets folder which is inside the public folder.

To import the font I am using below code in the `src/index.css`

```
 @import url("/public/assets/fonts/calibri/styleCalibri.css");
```

Can anyone suggest me how I can import this font?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible to import css files from public folder.
Instead use index.html file which located in public folder and add css file as Link
<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/style.css" type="text/css" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access `/public/assets/font` folder, you have to make a little change for your import. Just put `..` before `/public`.

```
@import url("../public/assets/fonts/calibri/styleCalibri.css");
```

or try to import it from `public/index.html` file like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/fonts/calibri/styleCalibri.css">
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I am getting same error of `Module not found: Error: You attempted to import ../public/assets/fonts/calibri/styleCalibri.css which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported. You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.`

Comment: i've updated my answer you can try this as well.

Comment: This will add link inside the root div but not in the head of the html. If I want to import it in the head of the body how I can do that?

Comment: I don't have `index.html`. I am using `index.tsx` which have `root.render(<AppWrapper />);`

Comment: in your public folder you'll find `index.html`.